# Arduino ledPin if else statement until value

Tags: if-statement, arduino

I have a question about my Arduino Leonardo. What I want to do with my Arduino is that the higher the value of AnalogWrite is, the more lights will go on. I've used a `if else` statement but I need a 'until value' function. Now all the lights will go on because I only used a < > but not a value from 0 till 50, 50 till 100 etc. Can somebody figure out how I need to write this?

```
int analogInPin = A3;
int sensorValue = 0;
int ledPin1 = 3;
int ledPin2 = 5;
int ledPin3 = 6;
int ledPin4 = 9;
int ledPin5 = 10;

int analogPin = 3; 

void setup() {    
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin5, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);

  Serial.println("sensor = ");
  Serial.println(sensorValue);

  delay(2);
  if ( sensorValue < 50 ) {
    analogWrite(ledPin1, sensorValue); 
  } else if ( sensorValue > 50 ) {
    analogWrite(ledPin2, sensorValue);
  }

  if ( sensorValue < 100 ) {
    analogWrite(ledPin2, sensorValue); 
  } 

  if ( sensorValue < 150 ) {
    analogWrite(ledPin3, sensorValue); 
  }  

}
```

Comment: If an answer help you, you should accept the answer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. I see that another question that you made, you don't accept any answer, and maybe you are new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your else if and your if (sensorValue < 100) will make two both if the value is between 50 and 100.

If I understand, you want to turn on the ledPin1 in range 0-50, led pin2 in range 50-100 and led pin 3 100-150?

```
if (sensorValue >= 0 && sensorValue <= 50 ) {
  analogWrite(ledPin1, sensorValue); 
  analogWrite(ledPin2, LOW); 
  analogWrite(ledPin3, LOW); 
}
else if (sensorValue > 50 && sensorValue <= 100) {
  analogWrite(ledPin2, sensorValue);
  analogWrite(ledPin1, LOW); 
  analogWrite(ledPin3, LOW); 
}
else if (sensorValue > 100 && sensorValue <= 150) {
  analogWrite(ledPin3, sensorValue);
  analogWrite(ledPin1, LOW); 
  analogWrite(ledPin2, LOW); 
}
```

Let me know if it's results!

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you. But now, if the value has been 20 and later be 0, the lights still be on (LedPin2). How can I make sure that they will go out if the value is zero again?

Comment: I correct my answer, I put > 0 , and you have to put >= 0 to go to zero!

Comment: It worked for ledPin1, but ledPin2 and ledPin3 are still be on. Should I do the same as ledPin1, ad => instead of >?

Comment: What is the wrong case now? No. Think in range of values.

Comment: The case now is that ledPin1 will go on if the value is 0 till 50, ledPin2 will go on from 50 till 100 and so on...

Comment: (sorry I entered but i wasn't finished) but if the value is 0 again, the lights are still on at ledPin2 and ledPin3. The problem is solved for ledPin1 but isn't for the other lights.

Comment: Because you have to turn off lights when you change if. Say me one thing, you cannot use digitalWrite(ledPin1,HIGH) for example? With this, you maake digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH) to turn on and digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW) to turn off.

Comment: I'm familiar with the digitalWrite but unfortunately I can't, I need to have analogWrite because the value is analog. How can I make sure the lights will go off? Should I make a if else statement to turn the lights off?

Comment: What is the function to turn off the lights? I try to change answer and help you!

Comment: It's for a assignment I need to do and I have to make sure that the lights only will go on depending of the analog's value. Thank you so much!

Comment: You need help you turn off the lights?

Comment: Yes, I do. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes. Say me only what is the function to turn off the lights with analogWrite and I edit my question for this situation. Like analogWrite(ledPin1, X) where X is the way to turn off the lights. You know what you have to put in X?

Comment: I edit my answer... My turnOff is the value that you have to set to turn off the lights. When you turn on a pin, you have to turn off the other pin's. Hope this helps! I think turn on is : 255 and turn off: 0 , but I think you know this better than me.

Comment: It was good except that 'turnOff' is not declared in Arduino so I changed it into 'LOW' and now its working! Thank you for your help.